# ng-bind-html : show loading icon while loading image

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have stored HTML code in Database and I load it on the fly. I have used `'ng-bind-html'` to load this HTML content in a view.

Now, I have some images in HTML code which I load on the fly, I want to show Loading Icon while Image is being loaded.

```
<div ng-bind-html="renderHTML(descData.description)"></div>
```

Controller to shoe rendered code.

```
scope.renderHTML = function(htmlCode)
{
     return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode)
};
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: could you show us what is content of `descData.description`?

Comment: Simple HTML Content. `<p><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5gx7vpJ4F8A/maxresdefault.jpg" ></p>`

Comment: how it is rendering on the page? any console error?

Comment: No, there is no error. It just append this content to respective div